# fopen in Mainframe (C language)

Tags: c, mainframe

I'm working on opening a file from the mainframe. currently, I can't access the input file I wanted. I don't know if there is something wrong with the C code or my JCL. Anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
int main()                                               
{                                                        

 FILE *ifp, *ofp;                                        

 printf("CTRACE1\n");                                    
 ifp = fopen("dd:INPUTF", "rb, recfm=vb, lrecl=50");     
 printf("CTRACE2\n");                                    
 ofp = fopen("dd:OUTPUTF","w");                          
 printf("CTRACE3\n");                                    

 fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), LINESZ, ifp );           
 printf( "Number of characters read = %i\n", num );

 printf( "buffer = %s\n", buffer );                         

 dstr = (DATASTR*) buffer;                                  

 printf("VAR_A = %.*s\n", sizeof(dstr->VAR_A), dstr->VAR_A);
 printf("VAR_B = %.*s\n", sizeof(dstr->VAR_B), dstr->VAR_B);
 printf("VAR_C = %.*s\n", sizeof(dstr->VAR_C), dstr->VAR_C);
 printf("CTRACE4\n");                                       

 x[sizeof(x)+1]='\0';                                       
 y[sizeof(y)+1]='\0';                                       
 z[sizeof(z)+1]='\0';                                       
 printf("CTRACE5\n");                                       


 memcpy(x, dstr->VAR_A,sizeof(dstr->VAR_A));                
 memcpy(y, dstr->VAR_B,sizeof(dstr->VAR_B));                
 memcpy(z, dstr->VAR_C,sizeof(dstr->VAR_C));                
 printf("CTRACE6\n");                                       

 printf("%s,%s,%s",x,y,z);                                  
 printf("CTRACE7\n");                                       

 fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), LINESZ, ofp);                 

 fprintf(ofp,"%s,%s,%s\n",x,y,z);                           


 fclose(ifp);                                               
 fclose(ofp);                                               
 return(0);                                                 
}
```

Here's my JCL:

```
...                                 
//*         TYPRUN=SCAN                                             
//JOBLIB    DD DSN=X543863.LOADLIB1,DISP=SHR                        
//STEP1     EXEC PGM=CCCGRATE                                       
//INPUTF    DD DSN=X543863.SAMPLE.INPUT01,DISP=SHR                  
//OUTPUTF   DD DSN=X543863.SAMPLE.OUTPUT01,                         
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                              
//            SPACE=(CYL,(1,1,45)),                                 
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=50)                               
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//
```

Comment: You need to add some error checking - never call `fopen` and just assume that it will be successful. And don't forget to check `errno` when `fopen` returns NULL.

Comment: if this is your starting point while dealing with both `C` and a mainframe, I highly suggest a switch to a more manageable scripting language like `python`.

Comment: what output do you get?  Do any of the CTRACE lines work?

Comment: @VorsPrung the ctrace lines work. the thing is, it can't access the input file for some reason.

Comment: @PaulR yup. I'll put the error checking after I get it working thanks.

Comment: Error checking should never be an afterthought - it helps with debugging and is an essential part of any program. Try and get into good habits in this regard.

Comment: @user2485710 look at the content of the Mainframe tag. z/OS has no python.

Comment: Take a look in the JESMSGLG DD of your job (select it with a ? in SDSF if you have it) and look for ICH messages indicating the external security manager has denied you access to your input file.

Comment: @BillWoodger than use LUA that apparently needs very minimum effort to be ported to zOS. If you have are experiencing a real problem you are probably gonna put some effort to solve it.

Comment: @user2485710 well, it's not my problem. And the problem is readily fixed with the existing code. Porting a programming language to many Mainframe sites would not get past the security/audit/compliance/regulatory procedures. If it is easy to port, it must be written in C/C++ (unless in one of specialist IBM internal languages, which seems unlikely). Why not let OP get the C example to work?

Comment: @BillWoodger a person comes to you with a really basic problem about a snippet written in `C` that he/she couldn't solve, he/she tells you that it's dealing with a mainframe: estimate the probability of a catastrophe inside that working environment. Plus scripting languages are much easier to maintain ( but I'm not saying that all the mainframes should run only scripts ); in this case it will probably be the only real solution in my opinion, and you can probably even find some ports online, I bet that more than 1 people on the planet are using scripting languages on a zOS.

Comment: The exchange with @user2485710 has lead me back to your code. Exactly what are you trying to do? Please describe as fully as possible, along with your knowledge of the content and source of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what output you get, at best it is difficult to say.

Are you trying to copy variable-length records to fixed-length records?

Two things. On the `fopen` for an input file you do not need to specify DCB information - so `recfm=vb` and `lrecl=50` are not needed (the information if not specified, will be taken from the JCL (if present) or from the catalog (which will be correct)).

Since they are not needed, you have probably got them wrong :-)

Take them off, and try your program.

Looking at what you have there and have specified for the output, either the vb is wrong (you are writing an fb) or the 50 is wrong (if you have 50 bytes of data, which you logically have from your fb definition, the the lrecl for a vb should be 54, because four bytes extra to the data are needed to include the RDW (Record Descriptor Word)).

The is nothing wrong with your JCL, but no way to tell whether the files and definitions of files are correct.

Down to you now. If you still can't fix it, provide all the likely information.

Comment: Hey bill. I tried removing the recfm=vb and lrecl=50 and still I cant get to access the input file. and thanks for answering. still a newb on running C on mainframe.

Comment: thanks bill! I got it working already. It was with th vb-fb thing. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

add an

```
#include <errno.h>
```

rewrite the open() calls to trap errors

```
if (!ifp = fopen("dd:INPUTF", "rb, recfm=vb, lrecl=50"))
  { 
  perror("ifp");
  exit(1);
  }     
 printf("CTRACE2\n");                                    
 if (!ofp = fopen("dd:OUTPUTF","w"))
  {
  perror("ofp");
  exit(1);
  }
```

And you should get a clue on why the input file does not work

Comment: Hey Vorsprung. I don't think the mainframe i'm using supports the errno.h library. I cant get it working on my code.

Comment: Look in the manuals for your "mainframe" (what sort of mainframe??) and see how to use perror or errno

Comment: Yes it does. errno.h is part of the standard C library, it works very nicely (speaking from experience).